# Halachic spelling of last names

Tags: divorce, ketubah, spelling-variants

What sources are there for learning how to spell last names in Hebrew? Especially, or halachic documents like kesubos, gittin, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I don't believe that ketubot require last names. My ketubah does not have it. Fortunately, I have not needed a get, so, I'm unfamiliar with the rules, there. However, I'm guessing that these also don't have last names. Can you specify which documents require last names? As you probably know, in general a person name is referred to as X ben / bat Y. So, overall, last names are not used.

Comment: In certain sepharadi communities, ketubot *do* include last names, c.f the following by R' Marc Angel: https://www.jewishideas.org/article/minhagim-divinity-and-diversity

The same article also brings down in the name of R' Daniel Sperber, that this is common place now among the Ashkenazim in Israel too.

Comment: helpful article https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/practical-halacha/writing-surnames-in-the-kesubah/

Comment: @Me. I can't access the link, now. If there are any guidelines to last names, please compose an answer. My own hunch - I don't think that there are "halachic guidelines" to transliterations for last names any more than there are guidelines to transliterating the city / town names placed on the Ketubah. (Try transliterating "Secaucus".) If you can find a uniform transliteration for "Braunschweiger" or similar "German" last names, I'd like to know what that is.

Comment: @DanF I wasn't suggesting that there is a "halachic" requirement to include the last name in the ketubot, neither does the article mention this "requirement" at all. I only made the comment because there was an answer here which (at least I thought) suggested, that lastnames are not mentioned in the ketubah at all.
The link  is just stating that it is a thing; without offering guidelines. If I had to guess, I'd say that in R' Angel's community they would be using some ladino syllabary which probably suffers from the same sort of ambiguity as hebrew/yiddish transliterations.

Comment: @Me. You're probably correct about the ambiguity. I've seen my last name transliterated in about 4 different ways.

Comment: @Dan I can guess אף עף אעף  and what's the fourth one?

Comment: I know that according to the Shach writes in Sh"A Choshen Mishpat siman 48 that names and monetary units be left blank. Also R. Chaim Avraham Zakutinsky writes in his book The Gates of Joy on wedding laws and customs that "If one is interested in adhering to the strict view of the Shach, one should make sure that the location, date, names, etc. be left blank, to be filled in at the wedding" page 219. My question is: what sources can I consult to learn to spell English locations, etc. in Hebrew.?

Comment: It's transliterated however you're used to transliterating it. My last name, for instance, is Hoerster, which my family spells as הערסטער. I'd assume a more "Hebraic" form would be הרסטר or הורסטר though.

Comment: You could start in Even Ha'Ezer  129:60 - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Even_HaEzer.129.60?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he - which discusses family names and their usage.